# How to toggle `helm-ff-skip-boring-files` during file navigation with `helm-find-file`?

Tags: helm, find-file

I'd like to be able, with a keystroke, to hide/show boring files during the file navigation in `helm-find-files`.

I defined a function

```
(defun mxl/toggle-helm-ff-skip-boring ()
  (interactive)
  (setq helm-ff-skip-boring-files (not helm-ff-skip-boring-files))
  (if helm-ff-skip-boring-files
      (message "Hide hidden files")
    (message "Show hidden files")))
```

and I bound it to `M-.` in `helm-find-files-map`. When I hit `M-.` I see the corresponding messages in the minibuffer, but the file shown by `helm-find-file` do not change. The behavior of `helm-find-files` seems to stick to the initial setting `helm-ff-skip-boring-files`. Is there some update function that I should call? Some cache clearing?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are missing a call to `helm-force-update` (or `helm-update)`, but also a bunch of other things.

Usually Helm actions come in pairs — one that you run via the action buffer and one that you run via a keybinding.  A good place to start with is to check how `helm-ff-toggle-basename` and `helm-ff-run-toggle-basename` are implemented.  After studying them, we can implement our own toggle for `helm-ff-skip-boring-files` quite easily:

```lisp
(defun helm-ff-toggle-skip-boring-files ()
  (with-helm-buffer
    (setq helm-ff-skip-boring-files (not helm-ff-skip-boring-files))
    (let* ((cand (helm-get-selection))
           (target (if helm-ff-transformer-show-only-basename
                       (helm-basename cand)
                     cand)))
      (helm-force-update
       (format helm-ff-last-expanded-candidate-regexp (regexp-quote target))))))

(defun helm-ff-run-toggle-skip-boring-files ()
  (interactive)
  (with-helm-alive-p
    (unless (helm-empty-source-p)
      (helm-ff-toggle-skip-boring-files))))
(put 'helm-ff-run-toggle-skip-boring-files 'helm-only t)

(define-key helm-find-files-map (kbd "M-.") 'helm-ff-run-toggle-skip-boring-files)
```

If you want the toggle to be also available in the action buffer, you would have to add something along the lines of `'("Toggle skip boring" . helm-ff-toggle-skip-boring-files)` to `helm-find-files-actions`.

Comment: That it perfect! Thank you!